# SpriteKit: Just wondering why my script won't work properly?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

just want it to make nodes fall random from anywhere on the top horizontal edge and fall down the page. without being half chopped off from the vertical edges. it currently shows a white screen

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@interface MyScene () <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];


    //physics world
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,-6);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
}
return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

}



-(void) addBalls {
    //create ball sprite
    SKSpriteNode *balls = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Ball.png"];
    balls.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:(balls.size.width/2)];
    balls.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

    //determine where to spawn balls
    int minX = balls.size.height/2;
    int maxX = self.frame.size.height - balls.size.height/2;
    int rangeX = maxX - minX;
    int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;

    //place ball slightly off shot, and along a random position on top edge
    balls.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.height + balls.size.width/2, actualX);
    [self addChild:balls];

    //speed of balls
    int minDuration = 2.0;
    int maxDuration = 4.0;
    int rangeDuraton = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = (arc4random() & rangeDuraton) + minDuration;

    //create the actions
    SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(-balls.size.height/2, actualX) duration:actualDuration];
    SKAction *actionMovedone = [SKAction removeFromParent];

    [balls runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[moveAction, actionMovedone]]];
}
```

just want it to make nodes fall random from anywhere on the top horizontal edge and fall down the page. without being half chopped off from the vertical edges. it currently shows a white screen

Comment: Where in the code are you calling the addBalls method?

Comment: Exchange the x and y values while setting the position of the ball

Comment: that fixed it thanks! i have one more question, how can i add more than one of a node to a scene? with    [self add child:node] it only makes 1.

Comment: You can wrap the code in a for loop, with the number of balls that needs to be added

Comment: I have added an answer with solutions to both problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to exchange the x and y values in the position of the ball nodes.

Secondly, to add multiple balls, you can modify the code as follows:

```
-(void) addBalls:(int)count
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        //create ball sprite
        SKSpriteNode *balls = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Ball.png"];
        balls.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:(balls.size.width/2)];
        balls.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

        //determine where to spawn balls
        int minX = balls.size.height/2;
        int maxX = self.frame.size.height - balls.size.height/2;
        int rangeX = maxX - minX;
        int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;

        //place ball slightly off shot, and along a random position on top edge
        balls.position = CGPointMake(actualX, self.frame.size.height + balls.size.width/2);
        [self addChild:balls];

        //speed of balls
        int minDuration = 2.0;
        int maxDuration = 4.0;
        int rangeDuraton = maxDuration - minDuration;
        int actualDuration = (arc4random() & rangeDuraton) + minDuration;

        //create the actions
        SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(-balls.size.height/2, actualX) duration:actualDuration];
        SKAction *actionMovedone = [SKAction removeFromParent];

        [balls runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[moveAction, actionMovedone]]];
    }
}
```

Then, simply pass the number of balls needed in the method.

Eg.

```
[self addBalls:10]; //Will add 10 balls to the scene
```

Comment: LIFESAVER! thanks so much! since your on a bit of role, i know someone has already given somewhat and answer, do you think you could help me with that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652571/spritekit-how-to-make-game-screen-view-move-upwards-as-node-jumps-along-the-y/23653067?noredirect=1#23653067

Comment: I'm receiving an error in the code above under initwithsize. [self addBalls]; no visible @interface for 'MyScene' declares the selector 'addBalls'. and when i don't add it to the initwithsize method they aren't there.

Comment: need 15 points, i don't have enough... when i do i will though. how do i accept?

Comment: That's because you are not passing any parameter with the addBalls method. You need to pass something like this: [self addBalls:10];

Comment: fixed up my issue, sorry my fault :D. thanks. I've applied what you wrote to non-dynamic "block" nodes that appear in the frame for the ball nodes to bounce off, is it possible to add something so that each block node can be a certain distance X and Y apart?

Comment: Yes you can, and this will be an interesting question once posted separately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654110/spritekit-separating-randomly-placed-non-dynamic-block-nodes-by-a-set-x-and-y


@akashg