# Spritekit: Separating randomly placed non-dynamic "block" nodes by a set X and Y value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

my script below does exactly what i need it to do, add blocks to a scene in any random order in the view. the only problem is, as i increase the amount of "block" nodes, they tend to overlap on one another and clump up, I'm wondering if there is a way i can add a "barrier" around each block node so that they cannot overlap but still give a random feel? My current code is below:

```
-(void) addBlocks:(int) count {
for (int i = 0; i< count; i++) {

SKSpriteNode *blocks = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Ball"];
blocks.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:(blocks.size.width/2)];
blocks.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
blocks.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
[self addChild:blocks];


int blockRandomPositionX = arc4random() % 290;
int blockRandomPositionY = arc4random() % 532;
blockRandomPositionY = blockRandomPositionY + 15;
blockRandomPositionX = blockRandomPositionX + 15;
blocks.position = CGPointMake(blockRandomPositionX, blockRandomPositionY);



}

}
```

Any help highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you set dynamic to YES, you will find that they will do so automatically

Comment: You can set `blocks.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO`
, to prevent them from falling.

Comment: oh my god, its beautiful! while that does somewhat solve the issue, is it possible to have a set amount? so that the nodes falling vertically can still pass through two nearby blocks?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. So you want them to be placed randomly, with a minimum distance between them, or make a pattern?

Comment: yes, placed randomly, but with a somewhat invisible and non interactive barrier around them, so that they can never be randomly spawned within a certain radius of each other?

Comment: That cannot be done implicitly. You will have to check this while adding the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent two nodes from overlapping, you should check the newly created node's random position with `intersectsNode:` to see if it overlaps any other nodes. You also have to add each successfully added node into an array against which you run the `intersectsNode:` check.

Look at the [SKNode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) for detailed information.